# Imagine you have a movie collection, and you want to write code that returns your review for each one. Here are the movies and your reviews:

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i am getting confused , how to do this task

> Imagine you have a movie collection, and you want to write code that
>   returns your review for each one. Here are the movies and your
>   reviews:
>
> ```
> "Toy Story 2" - "Great story. Mean prospector."
> "Finding Nemo" - "Cool animation, and funny turtles."
> "The Lion King" - "Great songs."
> ```
>
> Write a function named getReview that takes in a movie name and
>   returns its review based on the information above. If given a movie
>   name not found just return "I don't know!". Use a structure learned in
>   an earlier lesson (NOT if/else statements) to write this function.

```
var getReview = function (movie) {
    var a = ["Toy Story 2","Finding Nemo","The Lion King"]
    for(a[0]="Toy Story 2"){console.log("Great story. Mean prospector.")}
    for(a[0]="Finding Nemo"){console.log("Cool animation, and funny turtles.")}
    for(a[0]="The Lion King" ){console.log( "Great songs.")}
    };
```

some sugguest the rightway to doit.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What course is this? There are many ways to solve this, but the problem requires the use of "a structure learned in an earlier lesson," so we're unable to tell which is considered "the rightway to doit."

Comment: It might be a good idea to read this article on posting questions in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve You might get a better responce.

Comment: don't spam tags, there's no jquery or angular here. Then, this code is invalid and will definitely throw some syntax errors, you should read them, check your dev tools. `for` is a loop, not a `case`. `a[0]="Finding Nemo"` this is an assignment, not a comparison; and written as some kind of condition, always true. next, even as comparisons, these make no sense, why do you compare all of these values to the first item in the array? and you completely ignore the function argument. And finally, `Use a structure learned in an earlier lesson (NOT if/else statements) to write this function`

Answer (score 2):

Use an object to do this instead of an array. That way you can use the movie title as a key to find the review. This way the logic to retrieve data is simply to access the object - wrapping this in a function would be largely redundant. Try this:

```js
var movies = {
  "Toy Story 2": "Great story. Mean prospector.",
  "Finding Nemo": "Cool animation, and funny turtles.",
  "The Lion King": "Great songs."
}

var options = Object.keys(movies).map(function(k) {
  return '<option>' + k + '</option>';
})

$('select').html(options.join('')).change(function() {
  $('div').html(movies[this.value]);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select></select>
<div></div>
```

The important part of the above is the use of `movies[key]` to retrieve the review text.

Answer (score 2):

```
function getReview(movie) {
  const reviews = {
    "Toy Story 2": "Great story. Mean prospector.",
    "Finding Nemo": "Cool animation, and funny turtles."
    "The Lion King": "Great songs."
  }

  return reviews[movie] || 'Not Found'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create your data structure properly.

```js
var getReview = function (movie) {
 var array = [{
   "name": "Toy Story 2",
   "review" : "Great story. Mean prospector."
  }];
 
 var m = array.filter(x => x.name  == movie);
 console.log(m.length ? m[0].review : "Not Found")
};

getReview("Toy Story 2")
getReview("Toy Story 3")
```